# Как получить из списка элементы которые не повторяются в другом списке?

Tags: c#

Какой лучший (быстрее) способ получить из `List<string>` элементы - которые не повторяются в другом `List<string>` ?

**UPD - код**

```
        List<string> spisok1 = new(); // 25кк элементов
        List<string> spisok2 = new(); // 200к элементов

        foreach (var itemSpiska2 in spisok2)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < spisok1.Count; i++)
            {
                if (spisok1[i] == itemSpiska2)
                {
                    spisok1[i] = "";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (string itemSpiska1 in spisok1)
        {
            if (itemSpiska1?.Length != 0)
            {
                // Забрать элемент
            }
        }
```

**UPD - ответы на вопросы aepot**

*Пожалуйста дополните вопрос: 1) Как вы измеряли произодительность, что такое для вас "медленно" или "плохо"? 2) Что такое "быстрее"? Быстрее чем что? 3) Как вообще до такого дошло, что 25кк строковых элементов в список попали? Какую задачу вы решаете?*

1. По ощущениям
2. Быстрее - значительней быстрее чем сейчас
3. Это не так, но так объясню для простоты.
   Представим что 25кк это id вконтакте
   Вот в `spisok1` все необходимые для отработки `id`, а в `spisok2` когда то отработанные `id`.
   Вот и надо как то убрать / пометить в spisok1 ранее отработанные и взять потом часть не отработаннх xD

Comment: Покажите код, который вас не устраивает.

Comment: `Except` https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Если элементов много и повторов нет или их можно чистить, то лучше в `HashSet` списки перевести, тогда всё гораздо быстрее будет. Ну или хотя бы второй список перевести в `HashSet`, тогда `.Contains` будет быстро работать и можно опять же через `Linq` просто и быстро сделать. Можно и перебором, но в любом случае лучше делайте новый список по условию, а не удаляйте из старого.

Comment: @CrazyElf здесь не ясно, где тормозит у автора. Он же не показывает код. Вопрос на закрытие.

Comment: @aepot Ну без кода да, там что угодно может быть вообще, конечно

Comment: Пожалуйста дополните вопрос: 1) Как вы измеряли произодительность, что такое для вас "медленно" или "плохо"? 2) Что такое "быстрее"? Быстрее чем что? 3) Как вообще до такого дошло, что 25кк строковых элементов в список попали? Какую задачу вы решаете?

Comment: @aepot обновил и добавил код

Comment: @Blackmeser это именно string, в ответе aepot я просто предоставил пример для простого понимания что делаю с этими string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно всё сделать короче:

```
List<string> spisok1 = new(); // 25кк элементов
List<string> spisok2 = new(); // 200к элементов
var spisok3 = spisok1.Except(spisok2).ToList();
```

У меня отрабатывает секунд за 6, насколько быстрее Вам надо?

**UPD:** Добавил пример, который отрабатывает за 6 секунд.

```
List<string> main = new List<string>();
List<string> slave = new List<string>(); 
for (int i = 0; i < 25000000; i++)
{
    main.Add(i.ToString());
}
for (int i = 29999970; i < 50000000; i++)
{
    slave.Add(i.ToString());
}
var final = main.Except(slave).ToList();
```

**UPD2:** Данный метод ресурсозатратен.

**UPD3:** Тест производительности от @aepot

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var result = BenchmarkRunner.Run<ListTest>();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class ListTest
{
    readonly List<string> list1 = Enumerable.Range(1, 25000000).Select(i => "id" + i).ToList();
    readonly List<string> list2 = Enumerable.Range(123456, 200000).Select(i => "id" + (i * 3)).ToList();

    [Benchmark]
    public List<string> ExceptTest()
    {
        return list1.Except(list2).ToList();
    }
}
```

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.13.0, OS=Windows 10.0.19042.985 (20H2/October2020Update)
Intel Core i7-9700K CPU 3.60GHz (Coffee Lake), 1 CPU, 8 logical and 8 physical cores
.NET SDK=5.0.203
  [Host]     : .NET 5.0.6 (5.0.621.22011), X64 RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET 5.0.6 (5.0.621.22011), X64 RyuJIT
```

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ExceptTest | 5.023 s | 0.0129 s | 0.0107 s | - | - | - | 2 GB |

Сравнивать с `List.Contains` или `List.BinarySearch` не стал, потому что это долго ждать: они во много раз медленнее, хоть и потребляют значительно меньше памяти.

Comment: Что отрабатывает за 6 секунд? В этом коде нет выполнения Linq запроса, есть только его создание.

Comment: У себя я заполнил эти листы, дополню в ответе

Comment: `Except` действительно очень быстрый. Только на 25kk x 200k списках он лопает более 2 GB оперативы, но да, на моем Core i7-9700K CPU 3.60GHz отрабатывает за космические 5 секунд. Стоит отметить в ответе, что потребуется много памяти для выполнения. P.S. компактный код для наполнения `list1 = Enumerable.Range(1, 25000000).Select(i => "id" + i).ToList();`

Answer (score 5):

Попробуйте так

```
list1.RemoveAll(x => list2.Contains(x));
```

У меня в тесте list1 - 25к элементов, list2 - 2к элементов выполнилось за 1,97 сек.

**UPD**

Справедливости ради, при list1 = 25к, list2 = 20к у меня отрабатывает за 15с. Если использовать Except, как предложили выше

```
List<string> list3 = list1.Except(list2).ToList()
```

отрабатывает за 30мс, что в 500 раз быстрее.